# what will be the condition to check captcha

Tags: android, captcha

I am trying to check the captcha in my registration form which is generated statically in the project from a java file. But I am unable to trace the condition to check the captcha, all the time it is showing wrong. Whether captcha match or not it always shows invalid captcha. below is the code.

mainactivity.java

```
                      Submit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //isValidData();
            if (isValidData()){
                if (textCaptcha.checkAnswer(Usercapt.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    /*AlertDialog.Builder alt = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alt.setMessage("Invalid Captcha");
                    alt.setCancelable(true);
                    alt.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alt.create();
                    alertDialog.show();*/
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "captch match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else{
                   /* Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful Registration", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login_Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);*/
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "captcha not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } else {

                /*here the code to save the data in data base will be written*/
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registration Failed, Register again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
    });
```

Captcha.java

```
       package com.mws.tms_application;

   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.Color;

 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Random;



public abstract class Captcha {
protected Bitmap image;
protected String answer = "";
private int width;
protected int height;
protected int x = 0;
protected int y = 0;
protected static List usedColors ;

protected abstract Bitmap image();

public static int color(){
    Random r = new Random();
    int number;
    do{
        number = r.nextInt(9);
    }while(usedColors.contains(number));
    usedColors.add(number);
    switch(number){
        case 0: return Color.BLACK;
        case 1: return Color.BLUE;
        case 2: return Color.CYAN;
        case 3: return Color.DKGRAY;
        case 4: return Color.GRAY;
        case 5: return Color.GREEN;
        case 6: return Color.MAGENTA;
        case 7: return Color.RED;
        case 8: return Color.YELLOW;
        case 9: return Color.WHITE;
        default: return Color.WHITE;
    }
}

public int getWidth(){
    return this.width;
}

public void setWidth(int width){
    if(width > 0 && width < 10000){
        this.width = width;
    }else{
        this.width = 300;
    }
}

public int getHeight(){
    return this.height;
}

public void setHeight(int height){
    if(height > 0 && height < 10000){
        this.height = height;
    }else{
        this.height = 100;
    }
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return this.image;
}

public boolean checkAnswer(String ans) {
    /*System.out.println("ans received here"+ans);
    System.out.println("captcha"+answer);*/
    return (ans.equals(this.answer));


}
}
```

textcaptcha.java

```
         package com.mws.tms_application;

 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.Shader;

 import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Random;



 public class TextCaptcha extends Captcha {

protected TextOptions options;
private int wordLength;
private char mCh;

public enum TextOptions {
    UPPERCASE_ONLY,
    LOWERCASE_ONLY,
    NUMBERS_ONLY,
    LETTERS_ONLY,
    NUMBERS_AND_LETTERS
}

public TextCaptcha(int wordLength, TextOptions opt) {
    new TextCaptcha(0, 0, wordLength, opt);
}

public TextCaptcha(int width, int height, int wordLength, TextOptions opt) {
    setHeight(height);
    setWidth(width);
    this.options = opt;
    usedColors = new ArrayList<>();
    this.wordLength = wordLength;
    this.image = image();
}

@Override
protected Bitmap image() {
    LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, getWidth() / this.wordLength, getHeight() / 2, color(), color(), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setDither(true);
    p.setShader(gradient);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    c.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), p);
    Paint tp = new Paint();
    tp.setDither(true);
    tp.setTextSize(getWidth() / getHeight() * 20);

    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    CharArrayWriter cab = new CharArrayWriter();
    this.answer = " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < this.wordLength; i++) {
        char ch = ' ';
        switch (options) {
            case UPPERCASE_ONLY:
                ch = (char) (r.nextInt(91 - 65) + (65));
                break;
            case LOWERCASE_ONLY:
                ch = (char) (r.nextInt(123 - 97) + (97));
                break;
            case NUMBERS_ONLY:
                ch = (char) (r.nextInt(58 - 49) + (49));
                break;
            case LETTERS_ONLY:
                ch = getLetters(r);
                break;
            case NUMBERS_AND_LETTERS:
                ch = getLettersNumbers(r);
                break;
            default:
                ch = getLettersNumbers(r);
                break;
        }
        cab.append(ch);
        this.answer += ch;
    }

    char[] data = cab.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.x += (30 - (3 * this.wordLength)) + (Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % (65 - (1.2 * this.wordLength)));
        this.y = 50 + Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % 50;
        Canvas cc = new Canvas(bitmap);
        tp.setTextSkewX(r.nextFloat() - r.nextFloat());
        tp.setColor(color());
        cc.drawText(data, i, 1, this.x, this.y, tp);
        tp.setTextSkewX(0);
    }
    return bitmap;
}

private char getLetters(Random r) {
    int rint = (r.nextInt(123 - 65) + (65));
    if (((rint > 90) && (rint < 97)))
        getLetters(r);
    else
        mCh = (char) rint;
    return mCh;
}

private char getLettersNumbers(Random r) {
    int rint = (r.nextInt(123 - 49) + (49));

    if (((rint > 90) && (rint < 97)))
        getLettersNumbers(r);
    else if (((rint > 57) && (rint < 65)))
        getLettersNumbers(r);
    else
        mCh = (char) rint;
    return mCh;
}
}
```

Comment: where you asigned value to answer

Comment: it is get generated from another java file

Comment: does it contain letters? or numbers only the `answer` ?

Comment: I also checked the value which the edittext is throwing and the value generated by java file in the log statement, both came same when entered the correct captcha

Comment: it contains letters only

Comment: so you have another class, extends `Captcha`,  that class fills `answer` and implements `Bitmap image()` method ? can you show it plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it

you initialize `answer` with a space, not empty string:

```
this.answer = " ";
```

answer will be filled like this **" 1234567"** *notice the leading space*.

either initialize with empty string:

```
this.answer = "";
```

or use `trim()` on `answer` when compare

```
public boolean checkAnswer(String ans) {
    /*System.out.println("ans received here"+ans);
    System.out.println("captcha"+answer);*/
    return (ans.equals(this.answer.trim()));
}
```

recommended way is using empty string to initialize `answer`

Comment: thankyou @Yazan  , but it is working with trim(), it is not working with initializing empty string.

Comment: @ShubhamKanugo that's strange, is it possible that some of the methods can return a space based on `r`, ex `getLettersNumbers(r)` ?